# how can i set todays date as default date for a date field in page properties in cq5

Tags: extjs, aem

i have a date field(creation date) in page properties, which i want to default to todays date.

How i can accomplish this, i am using a listener on render event

even though i can read the value back, i cannot see to see the date set in page properties.

seems to me i am missing something basic

```
function(dateField) {

console.log("in render");
var todaysDate=new Date().format('m/d/Y');
console.log(todaysDate);
dateField.setValue(todaysDate);
CQ.Ext.getCmp("dateCreated").setValue(todaysDate);
console.log( CQ.Ext.getCmp("dateCreated").getValue());

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have set up your listener properly?  Can you make this work with a simple TextField?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a widget with xtype "**datetime**" and apply the value as "now", in order to initialize the date field with today's date in case the author hasn't selected any.

An example widget is shown below :

```
"date":{"fieldLabel":"datetime","xtype":"datetime","name":"./date","value":"now","jcr:primaryType":"cq:Widget"}
```

This would work for Pageproperties as well.

[Datetime widgets API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.from.DateTime).